# Can't get file upload to work in angular UI modal window

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, jquery-file-upload

Here is a plunker example of something that i'm trying to do:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dlktEzrBeFshGaZsTmg7?p=preview
Basically i just want to use jquery file upload inside the modal window.  as you can see in the plunker though, none of the callbacks are being called.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
      $log.log("done accessed");
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
      $log.log("fail accessed");
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        $log.log("progressall");
    },
    //add: function(e,data){
    //$log.log("add accessed");
    //},
    submit: function (e, data) {
        var notetext = $("#descModal").val();
        data.formData = { Description: notetext };
        $log.log("submit accessed");
    }
```

even the 'add' callback isn't being called when i add a file.  This all works fine if i use angular strap, but i'd rather not use that for other reasons.  I've investigated the modal initialization, and tried to override the windowTemplateURL

```
var theModal = $modal.open({ scope: $scope, templateUrl: modURL, controller: 'detailController', size: 'lg' });
```

(the default of which is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/modal/window.html ),and it looks like the problem is the 'modal-transclude' attribute.  Any ideas on getting past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Upgrade jQuery-ui to version 1.9.0 or higher.
2. Never use jQuery selectors in your controller, write a directive. E.g.

   ```js
   angular.module("myapp").directive("fileUpload", function($log, $parse) {
     return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var options = $parse(attrs.fileUpload)(scope) || {};

         element.fileupload({
           dataType: "json",
           url: "your url",
           done: function(e, data) {
             $log.log("done accessed");
           },
           fail: function(e, data) {
             $log.log("fail accessed");
           },
           progress: function(e, data) {
             options.progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
             scope.$apply();
             $log.log("progress");
           },
           submit: function(e, data) {
             $log.log("notetext:", options.notetext);
             data.formData = {
               Description: options.notetext
             };
             $log.log("submit accessed");
           }
         });
       }
     }
   ```

   And use it in this way:

   ```html
   <input file-upload="fileUploadOptions" type="file" multiple data-sequential-uploads="true" />
   ```

   Here's an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qLckEIlNLEcIfvwn4Q5x?p=preview
3. btw there is an example of the usage of this fileupload with angularjs: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html .

Comment: Thanks very much!  I guess i didn't realize how much jquery and angular don't really play with each other sometimes